# Reshaping 3D Numpy Array to a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the following 3D array in Numpy:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16]]])
```

when I write

```
b = np.reshape(a, [4,4])
```

The 2D resulting array will look like

```
 [[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11 12]
  [13 14 15 16]]
```

However, I want it to be in this shape:

```
 [[ 1  2  5  6]
  [ 3  4  7  8]
  [ 9 10 13 14]
  [11 12 15 16]]
```

How can I do this efficiently in Python/Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape to split the first axis into two, permute axes and one more reshape -

```
a.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
a.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,4)
```

Making it generic, would become -

```
m,n,r = a.shape
out = a.reshape(m//2,2,n,r).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,2*r)
```

Sample run -

```
In [20]: a
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]],

       [[13, 14],
        [15, 16]]])

In [21]: a.reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,4)
Out[21]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using just `np.hstack` and `np.vstack`:

```
In [98]: a
Out[98]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]],

       [[13, 14],
        [15, 16]]])

In [99]: s0, s1, s2, s3 = range(a.shape[0])

In [100]: np.vstack((np.hstack((a[s0], a[s1])), np.hstack((a[s2], a[s3]))))
Out[100]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Realizing the fact that your aim is to squash the first two slices of your original array into one slice and the next two into another slice and so on.

And you could also just replace the `np.vstack` and `np.hstack` with their fastest cousin `np.concatenate`, if you're concerned about performance.

P.S.: This approach creates a new array leaving your original one unchanged.